# How to catch fails in pdo batch insert

Tags: mysql, pdo, mysql-error-1064, batch-insert

I have this code to insert data from a CSV file to the database. Since, the CSV might have thousands of records, I am trying to implement a batch insert as follows.

```
$this->_connection->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbtable (col1,col2) VALUES (:value1,:value2)";
$stmt = $this->_connection->prepare($sql);

foreach ($requestArray['csv'] as $data) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':value1', $data['csvCol1']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value2', $data['csvCol2']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
$this->_connection->commit();
```

The variable $requestArray['csv'], holds all the record of the CSV post request. This code seems to be working as it should. Though, I am trying to improve it, because I want to let the user know how many records failed to insert on the database and if it is possible to show which records failed. Assume a duplicate key, or invalid data or generally any error that might come from this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

[PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) will return `false` on failure:

```
$this->_connection->beginTransaction();
$sql = "INSERT INTO dbtable (col1,col2) VALUES (:value1,:value2)";
$stmt = $this->_connection->prepare($sql);

foreach ($requestArray['csv'] as $data) {
    $stmt->bindParam(':value1', $data['csvCol1']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':value2', $data['csvCol2']);
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
      // error processing goes here.
    }
}
$this->_connection->commit();
```

Comment: Totally true! Thank you. I will go this way! I will try to add a try-catch there instead of if, so I can get the reason why this is happening each time. I guess this will work.